# Unable to build Haskell project with options -staticlib and -threaded on OSX

Tags: multithreading, macos, haskell, ghc, ffi

I'm having trouble building my Haskell library with GHC 7.8.2 and Cabal 1.20.0.2 on OSX 10.9.3 with both `-staticlib` and `-threaded` enabled.

The library I'm building exports several functions using FFI to be called from ObjectiveC in an Xcode project. This works fine with just `-staticlib` enabled, but now I realize I need to call into my Haskell library from multiple OS-threads simultaneously. But when I add `-threaded` to ghc-options I get an error when linking:

```
error: libtool: can't locate file for: -lpthread
error: libtool: file: -lpthread is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

Complete ouput:

```
$ cabal build
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring dpsync-0.1.0.0...
Building dpsync-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing library dpsync-0.1.0.0...
[ 1 of 11] Compiling Link             ( src/Link.hs, dist/build/Link.o )
...
[11 of 11] Compiling HsCocoa          ( src/HsCocoa.hs, dist/build/HsCocoa.o )
Linking liba.a ...
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lpthread
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lpthread is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

The linker command that fails looks like this (... replaces a bunch of -l and -L options):

```
libtool -static -o liba.a dist/build/HsCocoa.o ... -lCffi -lpthread
```

**Does anyone know what could be wrong?**

[Entire project on GitHub](https://github.com/froden/digipostarkiv)

**Edit:**

After discussing this on Haskell Cafe it was suggested that this could be a bug in GHC. I created a ticket here: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9189